# Euler Project 111 Code to make shorter and shorter

Tags: python-3.x

I am solving Euler Project # 111 problem, and the code I wrote is running for too long. How can I write this shorter, simpler, faster?
The problem is the link
https://projecteuler.net/problem=111

```
result = 0
a = []
count_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
for i in range(1000000000, 9999999999):

if i == 2:
    result += i
for j in range(1000000000, i):
    if i % j == 0:
        break
    elif j == i -1:
        a = list(str(i))
        for k in range(len(count_number)):
            if a.count(count_number[k]) == 1:
                break
            elif a.count(count_number[k] == count_number[k]):
                result += i
                del a

print(result)
```

Comment: Have you tried to check which parts are too slow?

Comment: This might be more on topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as you say the code is working correctly.